# Install error during Validate for "WDP files"

Tags: installation

Installing Sitecore 9.3 on-premise for myself, a developer.

First time installing Sitecore.  I've gone through the documentation and searched on Google, stack exchange, the Sitecore community, etc. for an answer and haven't found anything even close to what I am seeing.

During the "Validate" step in the UI driven installation, I get a red "X" next to "WDP files".  I kind of understand what WDP files are, but the error is still baffling.  I passed all requirements up to this point and I don't know how to get past this.

Installation logs do not contain any errors.

Comment: Could you share screenshot of the error that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide more information, maybe a screenshot or the step where this is failing.

Comment: Something was missing/corrupt from my installation files.  I re-downloaded and was able to install.  Thanks to all for comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try downloading `Graphical setup package for XP Single`  for
`Sitecore 9.3` from below url as shown in below screenshot https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/93/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_93_Initial_Release.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you faced this error:

[image]

The reason for this error is that for some unknown reason you don't have all `WDP files` within your installation folder. Sitecore needs it to install the instance. All WDP files have an extension of `.scwdp.zip.`

To fix your issue, try downloading again the installer from:
[https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/A1BC9FD8B20841959EF5275A3C97A8F9.ashx?date=20191213T115458](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/A1BC9FD8B20841959EF5275A3C97A8F9.ashx?date=20191213T115458)

or

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/93/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_93_Initial_Release.aspx, then select `Graphical setup package for XP Single`.

or if you're copying the installation folder from someone/somewhere pay attention if you copied all files, sometimes the `Windows` or the `Antivirus` blocks or excludes files without you realizing.

So make sure your installation folder contains `5` `.scwdp.zip` like the image below:

[image]

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I downloaded again and ran the install.  I was able to get past the error.  Thanks.  Doesn't explain why I got the error or what it means, but I'm on my way.

Comment: Nice, you're welcome! Perhaps some file was corrupt. Usually, this error indicates something wrong in your files.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's simply caused by too long paths on Windows (max path limit is 260 characters). I once faced the same issue when I extracted the `Sitecore installation package` that way that it created an additional folder with a long package name inside - so I had something like `Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.1.1-r4)\Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.1.1-r4)\installation` files here. The installation showed red x next to WDP files because paths to some of the `WDP packages` exceeded `260 characters`. Once I moved the files one level up, the installation went through without problems.